# Teamcity triggering a build on a merge

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

We currently having a problem with Teamcity triggering builds with a VCS trigger when there are 0 file changes, our VCS roots are configured with Mercurial

We have a checkout rules setup to only checkout the necessary folder for the solution we want to build and we have a requirement to only build a solution if there are changes in the folder that the solution belongs

The problem we are having is teamcity is triggering a build when there aren't any changes on the folder, this only happends when we merge heads.

[image]
The pending changes will show 0 files and if you view the file changes the files shown are from a folder that isn't included in the checkout rules or the VCS trigger.

I can't seem to figure this one out, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the "Root" path on your Version Control Settings page? Does it include the top level folder or the solution folder only?

Comment: Its set to the root path of the Repo, which will be the top level folder

Comment: Try setting it to the solution folder.

Comment: @Jonathan Did you resolve this? We are having the same issue.

Comment: @BitMask777 No we never did, gave up in the end :(

Comment: Could you post your VCS trigger rule configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess TC9 [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-buildTriggerRules) answers why this is happening. I know that this documentation is for newer version, but it seems to be about exact scenario you have.

> **Triggering a Build on Branch Merge**
>
> The VCS trigger is fully aware of branches and will trigger a build once a check-in is detected in a branch.
>
> When changes are merged / fast-forwarded from one branch to another, strictly speaking there are no actual changes in the code. By default, the VCS trigger behaves in the following way:
>
> - When merging/fast forwarding of two non-default branches: the changes in a
>     build are calculated with regard to previous builds in the same
>     branch, so if there is a build on same commit in a different branch,
>     the trigger will start a build in another branch pointing to the same
>     commit.
> - If the default branch is one of the branches in the
>     merging/fast-forwarding, the changes are always calculated against the
>     default branch, if there is a build on same revision in the default
>     branch, TeamCity will not run a new build on the same revision.

Comment: This sounds about exactly what was happening but that was a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks! It appears that this new behaviour was introduced in TC9. We just need to update :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the trigger rules? You can set a custom trigger rule to only run the build on changes to a specific folder.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-TriggerRulesExample

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what we have but only on a merge it will trigger a build when the changes came from another folder.
What I might do is add a blanket exclusion and see if that helps